# react-native : Body not allowd for GET or Head request

Tags: php, react-native, web-services

Im creating a web service to my app on react-native. But I always recieve the error "react-native : Body not allowd for GET or Head request". I was searching on internet , and all the people said that I  should change "GET" for "POST". The problem is that I had already change it, but it still throws the same error.

This is my code:

```
  const{UserName}=this.state;
    const{UserPass}=this.state;
    alert("OK"+this.state.UserName+" "+this.state.UserPass+" EH  ");
    fetch(,{
      nethod:'POST',
      header:{
        'Accept':'application/json',
        'Content-type' : 'application/json'
      },
      body:JSON.stringify({
        usuario:UserName,
        password:UserPass
      })
    }).then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) =>{
            alert(responseJson);
          })
          .catch((error)=>{
            console.error(error);
          })
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your fetch has a typo. nethod, should be method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've misspelt "method" on line 5